# Sometimes fragment not loads

Tags: android, fragment, bottomnavigationview

I have an android app with bottom navigation view and 3 fragments, and it just works fine but sometimes when I switch between two fragments (most of the time when I switch fast over and over) suddenly no fragment loads and shows a blank page. What should I do?

**UPDATE**

This is the code I wrote:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {

             if(item.getItemId() == R.id.logs) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,LogsFragment).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
            } else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.settings) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, SettingsFragment).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
            } else {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,HomeFragment).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
            }
            return true;
        });
}
```

```
   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId() == R.id.home) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,HomeFragment).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
        } else if(bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId() == R.id.logs) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,LogsFragment).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
        } else if(bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId() == R.id.settings) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, SettingsFragment).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to provide a [mcve] with question .

Comment: @ADM i provided the code